# Any "To Do" applet for Unity?

Tags: unity, applet

For gnome shell - a simple extension [exists](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/162/todo-list/). Is there any similar extension for Unity as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I found, Getting Things GNOME! is the best one. It has an indicator applet (You need to enable in preferences)

https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gtg

Answer (score 2):

No, currently there exists no *to-do-applet* for Unity.

However, there are softwares for doing the same. For example, you can have a look at *[Nitro](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/nitro/)*.

[image: Nitro availabe on the Software Center]

From [apps.ubuntu.com](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/nitro/):

> Nitro makes tasks management super easy and awesome. It's super fast,
>   simple and offline and can be used without an internet connection.
>   Nitro also packs Dropbox and Ubuntu one sync.

[image: Nitro Screenshot]

Comment: Thanks. But applet would be more handy for simple "To do" stuff

Answer (score 0):

## Hamster Indicator

The Hamster Indicator helps you keep track of your tasks, like the Gnome 3 "To Do" applet.

- Icon at the taskbar:

[image: icon]

- Dropdown menu:

[image: dropdown menu]

You can install it from the Ubuntu Software Centre:

[image]

Or from the Terminal with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install hamster-indicator
```

Comment: This is actually not similar to To do applet for the main reason you cannot view multiple activities with one click from the applet. You can get it in a slightly different way but its not the same. Even its philosophy. But thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be looking for something like [this](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/tomboy/).

[Tomboy Notes](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/tomboy/) is perhaps the only "to do" applet for unity. Fully customisable, and can also perch into the taskbar neatly :)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There exists a very small but really good application that does this task for you.

"Todo Indicator"

[image]

It shows you your tasks directly.

- to check you tasks you simply have to click on them
- to add a new task, you have to click on edit todo.txt  which opens your text editor.

For further instructions have a look at: [Webup8](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/04/todo-indicator-ubuntu-appindicator-for.html).

There you can also find deb packages and a ppa.